# Create Work Item using Azure DevOps Rest API using C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops, restsharp

I am unable to create Work Item using Azure DevOps REST API as mentioned in [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Request:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/MyTestProject/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=6.0-preview.3

Request Body:
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "Task2"
  }
]
```

Code to Get Response (Note this code works for all other POST Requests):

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result)
      {
         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
         JsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }

Response: 400
```

Can someone please suggest?

Comment: Did you try to add the `"from": null` element to the JSON, as outlined in the documentation? Did you set the content-type to `application/json-patch+json`, as indicated in the documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

application/json-patch+json is required.

Comment: Much appreciate you share the solution here. It would much better if you can accept this so that others could directly know this worked solution:-)

Answer (score 9):

It might be helpful to see your full example. However, here is a working example with `Newtonsoft.Json` (do not forget to create your PAT [create personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string PAT = "<personal access token>"; //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page
            string requestUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<my_org>/<my_project>/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=5.0";
            try
            {
                List<Object> flds = new List<Object>
                {
                    new { op = "add", path = "/fields/System.Title", value = "Title" }
                };


                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flds);

                HttpClientHandler _httpclienthndlr = new HttpClientHandler();

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(_httpclienthndlr))
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", PAT))));


                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), requestUrl)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json")
                    };

                    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can consider to use [.NET client libraries for Azure DevOps and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops). Here is the example: [Create a bug in Azure DevOps Services using .NET client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/create-bug-quickstart?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Hi Shamrai, here's a similar question you might be able to answer. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771092/azure-devops-rest-api-create-work-item-a-value-is-required

Comment: How can we add custom fileds?