# Azure DevOps REST API - Create Work Item - "A value is required"

Tags: node.js, rest, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a work item using the Azure DevOps REST API. I've been able to do other things, like running a WIQL query, but when I try to create a work item I get this mysterious triple-error:

> A value is required but was not present in the request
> A value is required but was not present in the request
> A value is required but was not present in the request

Here's the full response.

```json
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": {
        "Message": "A value is required but was not present in the request.\r\nA value is required but was not present in the request.\r\nA value is required but was not present in the request.\r\n"
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do, following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) as best I can.

*Note: as the accepted answer called out, the problem was a typo, an `&` immediately following the `?` in the URL. Since these examples otherwise work, for the benefit of anyone who wants to copy and paste, I've fixed the typo.*

### Minimal test case in NodeJS

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const username = '[username]';
const password = '[personal access token]'
const organization = '[organization]';
const project = '[project]'

const authorizationHeader = `Basic ${Buffer.from(
    `${username}:${password}`
  ).toString('base64')}`

const body = [
    { 
        "op":"add",
        "path":"/fields/System.Title",
        "value":"TestCreateWI"
    }
];


  fetch(`https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=6.0`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: authorizationHeader,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  }).then(async (response) => {    
    console.log(await response.text())
  });
```

#### Same request using CURL

```bash
curl 'https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization/MyProject/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=6.0' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic [redacted]' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' \
  --data-binary '[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"Test"}]'
```

#### Same request from a browser

Log in to DevOps so that your browser is pointing to `https://dev.azure.com/YourProject/YourOrganization`. Then open Dev Tools (F5) and paste this code into the JS console.

```js
const body = [
    { 
        "op":"add",
        "path":"/fields/System.Title",
        "value":"TestCreateWI"
    }
];

fetch(`${document.URL}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=6.0`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
}).then(async (response) => {    
  console.log(await response.text())
});
```

I know that it's reading my request, because if I change "op" to an invalid value, I get a different error. What am I missing?

Comment: I got a similar result, testing from PowerShell.  What you have looks right and aligns with the sample for their documentation.  You might just raise an issue on the developer community:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I've also posted on the VS developer community site. Someone there reported the same results and they're also using a Powershell script. Can you try their script and see if you get an error? That would tell us if the problem is in their code (and mine) or if there's an issue on the server that affects some accounts but not others. (I would try both of your scripts myself, but I'm on a Mac.) Thanks! https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1249605/azure-devops-rest-api-create-work-item-a-value-is.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a typo on your URL.  I duplicated the behavior in postman and resolved it by fixing the URL.  Most of the other answers with the calls "working" in PowerShell didn't copy your typo.

You specified `https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?&api-version=6.0`

It shouldn't have the extra & before the api-version `https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=6.0`

Answer (score 1):

I do not use curl on my tasks, but the following works on my org:

```
curl -u "":personal_access_token -d "[{\"op\":\"add\",\"path\":\"/fields/System.Title\",\"value\":\"Sample task\"}]" -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" -X POST https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_apis/wit/workitems/${Task}?api-version=6.0
```

I`ve tested curl for windows 7.73.0.

Docs to create a personal access token: [Use personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page). Additionally, use the work item type in url like `${work item type name}`

If I post data with `-d '[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"Sample task"}]'` the service returns the following answer:

> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"You must pass a valid
> patch document in the body of the
> request.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException,
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common","typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error about "valid patch document" is because you haven't escaped the quotes so the JSON object is not valid. Since I'm using `--data-binary` I don't have to escape the quotes. I can reproduce the error you're getting by putting an "x" in front of the JSON, rendering it invalid. Anyway, the fact that it works for you and you're not really doing anything different suggests the problem is specific to my org. That's at least a little bit helpful. +1

Answer (score -1):

> Azure DevOps REST API - Create Work Item - “A value is required”

I could use the REST API [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to create the workitem with Powershell task in my pipeline:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=6.0
```

The request body is:

```
  [
    {
      "op": "add",
      "path": "/fields/System.Title",
      "value": "TestCreateWI"
    }
 ]
```

Below is my powershell scripts:

```
$connectionToken="$(PAT)"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$url= 'https://dev.azure.com/MyCustomOrganization/MyTestProject/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=6.0'

$body=@"
  [
    {
      "op": "add",
      "path": "/fields/System.Title",
      "value": "TestCreateWI"
    }
 ]
"@

Write-Host "$url"
$response= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url  -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $body -headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST
```

The test result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I can’t see any difference other than you’re using powershell. I’m not on Windows so I can’t try your script. Ultimately I want the call in a NodeJS script. I used curl in the question to reduce it to the simplest possible test case.

Comment: I've updated my question with two more examples. One uses NodeJS and the other can be executed in DevTools in a browser.

Answer (score -1):

You can try substituting `'` for `"` on both sides of the URL in your script.

I tried the PowerShell script provided in [the link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1249605/azure-devops-rest-api-create-work-item-a-value-is.html) you provided and successfully reproduced the error.

[image]

After I changed the `'` on both sides of `$uri` to `"`, I was able to successfully create the work item.

In addition, during my tests, I used `%24` instead of `$` in the URI, otherwise an error would be reported.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/%24{type}?api-version=6.0
```

PS. My test environment is Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on a Mac so I can't test Powershell, but I did try replacing the `$` with `%24`. I've updated my question with examples using NodeJS and a browser. Can you try reproducing with one of those examples?